# UnityPlayer on Android asks for permissions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions

I'm working on a Unity project (5.3.1) integrated in an Android native app. I put a few `uses-permission` in the manifest, that of course are not expected to be requested until I do in runtime. The problem is that they are all requested once in the android native code I instance the UnityPlayer module. I decompiled it and found that there is some permissions requests not needed, as you can find also in what this other guy found decompiling UnityPlayer for Android:
https://github.com/eppz/Unity.Labs.Unity_Player_Android/blob/master/com/unity3d/player/n.java

Any experience on Unity Engine that "scans" for permissions when not needed, activating the permission requests?

Answer (score 0):

Found that it's a "strategy" of some versions of the Unity Player for Android 6.0 permissions. They provided a meta-tag to be added in the manifest as explained in
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-bug-fix-problem-android-6-urgent.367681/page-2#post-2649810 By the way it was difficult to find the right Unity version that worked with my code and plugins. It looks like the issue has been fixed differently in Unity 5.2.4, 5.3.3, 5.4.0 (that I tried)